# Azure AD | Conflict when logged in with another Azure Account

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I have a Asp.net MVC application that uses Azure AD and OpenID Connect OWIN middlewares to handle authentication. Everything works fine except for one thing : if a user is already logged-in on another Microsoft Application lets say a Office 365 account or maybe a live mail account, when trying to login it recives a page saying that it is not allowed to log into my app, which is correct, but some how I need to catch that situation in my code to allow the user to sign in with a different account. Is there a way of doing that? This is by design? I mean : the user have to log in only with a live/azure account at the time ? I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today there is typically one user at a time, but we will soon support for you a way to select a specific user instead of automatically signing you in with the most recent one.
One way you can work around this today is by injecting the parameter "prompt=login" in your sign in requests. You can do that in the RedirectToIdentityProvider notifications, similarly to what is showin in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/ for domain_hint. This will cause the sign in experience to always start with a fresh prompt even if the user is already signed in. The draw back is that you'll never get SSO this way. Hopefully our account switiching feature will become available soon, keep an eye on http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/ for announcements

Comment: Thanks Vitorio! It helped me a lot ! It would be great to have that feature on Azure AD.